# Does removing a user from a Google doc remove their comments?

Tags: google-docs

I am editing a document on Google Docs, and I've shared it with a few users. I would now like to remove those users from the list of users that the document has been shared with, but I don't want to lose their comments.

If I un-share the document with these users, will I lose their comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Un-sharing a document with a user does not remove their comments or their suggested changes in Google Docs.